# Cannot read data from database into arraylist?

Tags: c#, database, sqoop

I have tried to solve this but i get a crazy error when i do this?

Here's my first method --> Which holds the SQLQUERY

```
[WebMethod]
 public ArrayList getAllaEgenskaperforenmall(string mall_id)
 {
     ArrayList dbFetch;
    // string parameter1 = "mall_namn";
     string sqlReadQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT d.egenskaper_namn FROM(SELECT egen.egenskaper_id, egen.egenskaper_namn, kopp.mall_id, kopp.egenskap_id, emall.mall_id as egenskapensmallid, emall.mall_namn FROM t_egenskaper as egen, t_kopplingmallegenskaper as kopp, t_egenskapsmall as emall  WHERE kopp.mall_id = 1  AND kopp.egenskap_id = egen.egenskaper_id) as d";

     dbFetch = executeReadSqlQueryArray(sqlReadQuery);

     return dbFetch;

 }
```

Then I have tried to set up a general webmethod that could fetch data for me.

```
 public ArrayList executeReadSqlQueryArray(string sqlToFetchData, string parameter1 = "", string parameter2 = "", string parameter3 = "")
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(mConnectionstring);
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
     SqlDataReader sqlReader;
     ArrayList dataReadFromDatabase = new ArrayList();

     command.Connection = conn;
     command.Connection.Open();
     command.CommandText = sqlToFetchData;


     sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while(sqlReader.Read())
    {

        object[] values = new object[sqlReader.FieldCount];
        sqlReader.GetValues(values);
        dataReadFromDatabase.Add(values);
    }
    command.Connection.Close();
    return dataReadFromDatabase;

}
```

The error i get is this? Funny thing is that yesterday I think I managed to get it to do as I wanted!

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.Object[] may not be used in this context.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write1_Object(String n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write8_ArrayOfAnyType(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayListSerializer2.Serialize(Object objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.Write(HttpResponse response, Stream outputStream, Object returnValue)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues, Stream outputStream)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
```

Comment: Do you have to use an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Recommend against handing back List<Object[]> (or ArrayList containing Object[]) - it's a terrible API for someone consuming it to work with. No type information, so no way to detect a breaking change when you change the webmethods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with your code from getting from the DB as such, its that the WebMethod is trying to turn it into a string but it doesn't know what datatype it is. Currently its cast as Object (which can mean one of a million types).

If the datatype is of a simple singular data typeTry swapping away from ArrayList and making it a generic array, for example

```
List<String>
```

The problem is your array list contains a list of objects currently and the serialization processor doesn't know what to do with them. You could hard cast them from objects to a `serializable` format though to help or switch to a class (and make that implement `serializable`).

For example

```
[Serializable]
public class ProfileBasics
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Gets or sets the about me section
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("AboutMe")]
    public string AboutMe {get; set;}

    /// <summary>
    ///   Gets or sets the city name for the zip code
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("City")]
    public string City {get; set;}
 }
```

Then you could do `List<ProfileBasics>` and your web service should still work.

Comment: Definitely agree that you should have a better serialization format. Is there a reason you're using ASP.Net 3 style webmethods and XML rather than JSON?

Comment: Not sure if that's directed at me or the OP. The answer I gave was just to fit in with the OP question, since I seen [WebMethod] I used the XML format, I realise you can change this to JSON but figured to go with the defaults since it'd have a higher chance of covering requirements.

Comment: Intended for the OP. Questioning assumptions seemed logical since 1.1 data structures were being used, though...